# How could i delay an auto play audio /html5 by jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, computer-science

I have an autoplay audio in my page , its html5 audio  when i open the webpage the audio directly plays , I want the audio be delayed three seconds then it plays ..

This is the code

```html
<div class="audio">
            
                <audio autoplay> <source src="loading/harely.mp3" type="audio/mp3">  </audio>
            
            </div>
```

I tried this way by jquery , but the audio didn't delay

```js
    $('.audio').delay(3000).append('<audio autoplay> <source src="loading/harely.mp3" type="audio/mp3">  </audio>');
```

```html
<div class="audio">


</div>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple delay function

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
    // code here
}, 3000);
```

Comment: Thank you it works .. this is what i did

   setTimeout(function(){ 
    
            $('.audio').append('<audio autoplay> <source src="loading/harely.mp3" type="audio/mp3">  </audio>');
    
    
    }, 3000);

i wondered that i could use jquery method inside pure js function

Comment: jQuery is a set of JavaScript libraries. So all the jQuery functions will work in pure JS functions.

Comment: Thank you .. and why the jquery delay function doesn't work ?

Comment: Difficult to answer without full source code. please look after console error message.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is much better to not mess with HTML elements, and using function JavaScript instead.

```
let playNow = function() {
 let audio = new Audio('YourMusic.mp3');
audio.play();
}

setTimeout(function(){ 
    playNow();
}, 5000);
```

See [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/j8voy3w5/)

Comment: This is one of the best ways to get people that think like I do to close your page and never re-visit it. Any page that creates an audio element that isn't in the DOM and makes it play automatically will be viewed as worse than a full-page advertisement.

Comment: @enhzflep Yep! I think so... But it was just a solution, not a UX advice.

Comment: nothing explicitly prevents offering a solution that provides both.

Comment: @enhzflep there are other answers here that provide the other way, and it was just my idea for this solution. I will try to write the answer by using the HTML element too. it is not much different, the code just needs a simple change

Comment: Thank you i will use this way

Answer (score 1):

Rather than making life hard for anyone that attempts attempts maintenance of the page, why not simply put an audio element into the html (without the autoplay attribute set) and then use javascript to start it playing?

Something like the following will do it. (it doesn't work here in the page, since the src is invalid)

```js
function byId(id){return document.getElementById(id)}

window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);

function onDocLoaded(evt)
{
  setTimeout( function(){ byId('myAudioElem').play() }, 3000 );
}
```

```html
<audio id='myAudioElem' src='yourAudioFilenameHere.extension'></audio>
```

This presents a number of advantages over other suggestions thus far:

1. There is an element clearly defined in the HTML - this:

   - makes maintenance easier
   - allows users that object to find and remove it from the DOM
2. The browser begins to download and decode the audio immediately at the time the page is loaded. This helps ensure that it actually does begin playing after 3 seconds, rather than happening at some time after this - a time that will depend on the connection speed and the cpu speed of the viewing device.

You can easily hear the difference if you instead use a function for `setTimeout` like the following, making sure to specify the same audio-file as is done in the DOM - you'll get a noticeable echo when playing from localhost and an even larger (longer) echo when loading an element from another server.

```
 setTimeout( 
                function()
                { 
                    var audio = document.createElement('audio'); 
                    audio.src = 'yourAudioFilenameHere.extension';
                    audio.play();

                    byId('myAudioElem').play() 
                }, 
                3000 
            );
```